# Read excel calculated fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I am using Angular2 and i would like to read an excel file cell values for calculated fields.
I have tried `SheetJS` https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx library and for calculated fields i get a formula not the value - shown i in the excel cell.

[image]

Is there a a way for getting calculated value directly from the excel field in javascript?